# Is it typical for windows in Lima to let some air go through even when the windows are closed?

Tags: accommodation, peru, lima

Is it typical for windows in apartments in Lima to let some air go through even when the windows are "as closed as possible"?

Examples (red rectangle indicates air going through):

[image]    [image]

Comment: Didn't you ask this question a few weeks back, already? Are you going to answer the many questions you had during your trip, yourself? Answers might interest other readers.

Comment: I don't know about Lima but I have seen similar things in São Paulo. There was no heating in the apartment, and I don't think there was even AC

Comment: You've already asked and then deleted https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151072/is-it-typical-for-windows-in-lima-to-let-some-air-go-through-even-when-the-windo. Any reason to recreate?

Comment: @JonathanReez got automatically deleted

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I typically answer when I become aware of the answer

Comment: This is also true for pretty much every home in England. ;-)  It's called involuntary ventilation and a product called "double glazing film" is quite effective at stopping it.

Comment: Your picture is blurry.  Please post a better picture.  And this probably fits better on [DIY.SE]?

Comment: @gerrit thanks I hadn't heard about double glazing window, that's great to know! Does it focus solely on thermic isolation, or does it also act as a decent sound isolation solution as well? Sorry for the blurriness, I really need to learn how to disable the quite imperfect autofocus feature in the built-in camera application on Samsung S9 phones. I'm currently in the US in a place with truly isolating windows so I won't be able to to retake the picture in the near future though.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't think it stops any sound, it just reduces the heat loss and draft.

Comment: Double glazing is known as double-paned (or even triple-paned) windows in the US.

Comment: @mkennedy Thanks, good to know, I also wasn't aware of this synonymy. I'd point out that from understanding gerrit was mentioning the film version, which can me added on top of a window.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Some answers in the comments:

> In general yes. You will see a lot in South America. There is not much need for better insulation, and because of gas (hot water, and kitchen) where is need of ventilation. But so often (but on private properties) there is a sign about not putting something to block ventilation. – Giacomo Catenazzi ↵ Dec 17 '19 at 11:24
>
> I don't know about Lima but I have seen similar things in São Paulo. There was no heating in the apartment, and I don't think there was even AC – Peter M ↵ Jan 20 at 22:11
>
> This is also true for pretty much every home in England. ;-) It's called involuntary ventilation and a product called "double glazing film" is quite effective at stopping it. – gerrit ↵ Jan 21 at 8:45